# NSURLConnection JSON doesn't post data

Tags: php, iphone, xcode, json, nsurlconnection

I'm creating a login Page in my iPhone app and I use Json to call a PHP page to connect to a MySql database.

I have the connection with the PHP page but my program doesn't post anything.

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender{


        //Alloc dictionary
        jsonDictionaryLogin = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: securityCode, @"hash_app", loginTextField.text, @"app_email", passwordTextField.text, @"app_password", nil];

        NSError *jsonError = nil;
        jsonDataLogin = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionaryLogin
                                                        options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];

        if(!jsonError) {

            NSString *serJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonDataLogin encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"\n\nSerialized JSON: %@", serJSON);

        } else {

            NSLog(@"JSON Encoding Failed: %@", [jsonError localizedDescription]);
        }


        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/mypage.php"];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];



        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonDataLogin length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-Length"];

        [request setHTTPBody:jsonDataLogin];
        NSLog(@"jsonData: %@",jsonDataLogin);


        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:true];

        [connection start];   
    }
```

After, in my delegate method:

```
-   (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData{

    NSLog(@"String sent from server %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

}
```

My PHP code:

```
<?
    $hash = $_POST['hash_app'];

    echo json_encode(array("TEST" => "swrao")); //RETURN swrao

    echo json_encode($hash); //RETURN null

        if($hash == "string_sended")
    {

         echo json_encode(array("TEST" => "YOU ARE IN")); //NO RETURN

        }


?>
```

The String from the NSLog give some message that i have written in PHP page, but the PHP page doesn't not receive the data sended.

Some idea?

Comment: Check for `jsonDataLogin == nil` to determine if there is an error.

Comment: Use a network sniffer (I use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com)) to see exactly what is sent and the return code.

Comment: Made. jsonDataLogin != nil

Comment: The network sniffer says me that i send the right request.